# Sometimes the contact key is not updated

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I'm using Marketing Cloud to send push notification to our Android users. I also need that the contact key is valorized as userId when the user performs the login.
So in the same transaction, I update the contact key (with the user id) and another field that contains the user id too.
This is the snippet of code:

```
MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk {
        it.registrationManager.edit().run {
            attributesToSet.forEach { attribute ->
                setAttribute(attribute.key, attribute.value)
            }

            if (contactKey != null && contactKey.isNotBlank()) {
                setContactKey(contactKey)
            }
            commit()
        }
    }
```

The `attributesToSet` is a Map and an entry has the "user_id" as key and the user id value (e.g. 10102334) as value.
The `contactKey` contains the user id value too.

In some rows of my Mobile Push table I see that the `user_id` column is valorized and the corresponding `contactKey` is not equal to the user id.
This is strange because the updating of the `contactKey` and `user_id` columns is done in the same transaction.

Someone have any suggestions about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The only requirements for `Contact Key` are that it is not null, does not contain only whitespace characters and that it is less than 100 characters in length.  We do not currently enforce the length requirement in the SDK as that could be changed server side.  Also, there is a uniqueness requirement that we cannot enforce in the SDK, but that would be unrelated to your question, though I figured it was worth calling out here while documenting other requirements.

What does the output from [getSdkState()](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html#evaluate-the-sdk-state) show for your registrations?

You should open a support request through your account executive for this issue so that we can better assist you -- we have no known issues with `Contact Key` operations in the SDKs.